# Мессенджер в локальной сети

Tags: c#

Я сейчас на 4 курсе, и вскоре буду проходить производственную практику, поэтому заранее нашёл себе место и договорился с работодателем, а так же получил от него примерное описание того, что мне нужно будет сделать в течение практики, а именно: Создать мессенджер, которым будут пользоваться работники производства, и работать он должен с помощью локальной сети, потому что она намного более быстрая, чем глобальная.

Имею некоторый опыт работы с .NET и C# непосредственно, поэтому реализовывать решил именно на этом языке, но никогда прежде с подобной задачей не сталкивался, и, можно сказать, это мой первый более-менее серьёзный проект, поэтому прошу помощи в плане оценки этой задачи, то есть, насколько долго и сложно будет её выполнить (По учёбе тоже нужно сдавать проекты и так далее, не на одной практике мир держится), и, самое главное, откуда начать и в каком направлении двигаться? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. [«Как задать хороший вопрос?»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: То, что вы рассказали - это не задание, это просто какая то хотелка. Задание должно включать хотя бы какие то требования. Что у вас с аутентификацией? Авторизацией? Нужны ли роли пользователям? Будет ли пересылка только текста или также файлов? Как вы соьираетесь доставлять клиенты и обновления конечным юзерам? Если вопрос только о самом простом мессенджере, поставьте им скайп или lync или на худой конец jabber и ничего не надо программировать.

Comment: Прежде чем начинать писать определитесь, что и как будет делать клиент и что и как будет обрабатывать сервер. Далее определитесь что вы будете передавать между клиентом и сервером и в каком виде будет эта информация - STRING, XML, JSON, BINARY DATA. А уж потом, когда каркас проекта сформируется, возьмитесь за изучение модулей - сетевая часть и GUI. Т.е. техническое задание первично, а форма исполнения вторична. А то, как вы описали только подходит под определение "сферический конь в вакууме".

Comment: Данные задачи в производственной практике решаются существующими инструментами, а не написанием нового велосипеда. А так возможно будет и долго и сложно, если нет наставника и опыта в написании таких приложений. А возможно и быстро, если сразу разберетесь с клиент-серверными приложениями.

Comment: SIgnalR в помощь, займет от силы 3-4 дня (больше времени уйдет на создание дизайна/форм/страниц)